# Redirect from login page

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have the following login script for facebook oauth2 authentication:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
           cookie: true, xfbml: true});
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

Can you guys tell me how to redirect the user upon succesful login depending on:
1) Is it the first time the user logs in (where he allows the app to extract data)

2) Is it an existing user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by initializing the OAuth dialog with this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=CANVAS_URL?isNew=1
```

At your CANVAS_URL page you can get the 'isNew' parameter and therefore know that the user is new.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response Martin. 
However I'm new to facebook programming, so I'm not sure where to add the above URL. 

Say my redirect upon existing user is example.com/existing and on new users example.com/new. Can you specify exatly what to do in this case? – Mikkel 1 min ago edit

Comment: Are you requesting basic permission from the users that come to your app? Check out this [topic](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: I would prefer using PHP for the authentication.

Is it possible to do something like this:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/
for oauth2?

Comment: Well, in PHP you can parse the signed_request param, as described in the topic I gave you link to, and if the signed_request does not include 'user_id' this is a good indication that the user has not given you permission. If so, what you do is: **echo "<script>top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=CANVAS_URL?isNew=1 '</script>";** - that way the user will be prompted with the OAuth dialog

Comment: Thanks again. However, the above suggestion redirects to a new facebook window.

I prefer using 

      <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      FB.init({appId: '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>', status: true,
               cookie: true, xfbml: true});
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
    </script>

As this script opens the login in an iframe. Isn't is possible to specify redirect parameters for new and existing users there?

Comment: Of course it is, if you specify **window.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=CANVAS_URL?isNew=1'** instead of reloading.